# How to make my glass completely transparent

Tags: glass

[image]

So I am trying to make a jar of fireflies. Currently in this picture I only have 1 sphere that is emitting green light, however as you can see the refraction of the glass is causing it to look as though there are a couple and making the others look pixelized. IS  there any way that I can fix this?

Comment: Did you try using Principled BSDF? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/principled.html

Comment: Where would I put it? Sorry I am new to blender.

Comment: Does your jar mesh have thickness? If the sides are a single surface (with no ‘inner’ surface to give the glass sides thickness) then it will be rendered as a solid block of glass. Try adding a Solidify modifier to you mesh.

Comment: it didn't seem to work